# texorpdfstring with two arguments

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, pdf

The space between the first and the second chapter is different. I know the issue is with the newcommand `\chapterAndAuthor` with the `texorpfdstring` command. I added the command `texorpfdstring` to get no format settings in the bookmarks. Without the `texorpfdstring` the format setting working fine. So I read the `texorpfdstring` comes with two arguments, but anyway I can't handle it. Please have a look at the img.(I know `KOMA`, `titlesec` and `titletoc` is not a good way). `\parbox[t]` is not a good solution for me, because the page number is not behind the dots...

```
\documentclass[10pt,final]{scrbook}

\usepackage{titletoc} % modify toc title
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage{anyfontsize} % change fontsize
\usepackage{tocloft} % design toc
\usepackage{framed, xcolor}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\urlstyle{same}


\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\normalfont{Contents}}}
% section itshape
\titleformat*{\section}{\itshape}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\itshape}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0cm}{0.84cm}{0.42cm}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0cm}{0.84cm}{0.42cm}
% Spacing between chapter and author
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0cm}{0.84cm}{0.42cm}
%%% Chapter style
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{12pt}{\Large}

% Display chapters in the Table of Contents
\titlecontents{chapter}
  [0pt]% Left margin, optional
  {}% Code insertet above
  {\mdseries}% Numbered-entryformat
  {\mdseries}% Numberless-format
  {\contentspage} % add dotfill and pagenumber, and some vertical space between entries

% Custom command to keep the author on the same page of chaptertitle, and above it.
\newcommand{\chapterAndAuthor} [2]{
 % #1: Author
 % #2: Chaptertitle
\clearpage%
    % Minipage to keep the author and chaptertitle on same page
    \noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        % Set the author style
        {\selectfont\fontsize{12}{14} \itshape{#1}}
        % Bring the chaptertitle closer to the authortitle
        \vspace{-3\baselineskip}
         % Add an entry to the Table of Contents, with the name of the author in emph and the chapter title
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\texorpdfstring{\normalfont #1\vspace{1ex}\newline
    % For long chapter titles using a \parbox
    \hspace*{1em}\protect\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{#2 \dotfill}}{#2}}
  % Print the chapter
        \chapter*{#2}
    \end{minipage}
    }


% space between table of contents
\setlength\cftparskip{0.21cm} 
\setlength\cftbeforesecskip{10pt}
\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{10pt} 
%pagestyle%
\usepackage[paperheight=21.0cm,paperwidth=13.5cm,twoside,textwidth=10.3cm,textheight=16.3cm,nohead,pdftex]{geometry}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\chapterAndAuthor{The name of the first author, The name of second author and The name of the third author}{Test Chapter One Test Chapter One Test Chapter One Test Chapter One Test Chapter One Test Chapter One Test Chapter One}
\lipsum[1-4]
\vspace{0.84cm}
\subsection*{Subheading1 without indentation}
\lipsum[1-4]
\subsection*{Subheading2 without indentation}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection*{Subheading3 without indentation}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapterAndAuthor{The name of the second author}{Test Chapter Two}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I deleted my answer -- I can't help you here.

Comment: The moment i got confused was `\chapterAndAuthor` having the author as the first argument and chapter as the second, whereas the name implies something different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should enclose everything in a `\parbox`, not just the chapter title.

By the way, you should not load both `titletoc` and `tocloft`. The `-15pt` bit should correspond to some parameter in `titletoc`, find out which one.

Add also a better separation between titles in the TOC.

I removed most of the unnecessary package for the example. Changing `\contentsname` into Contents for the German language is dubious: if the document is in English, with parts in German, switch the position of the languages in the declaration: `\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,draft]{scrbook}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc} % modify toc title
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\urlstyle{same}

% section itshape
\titleformat*{\section}{\itshape}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\itshape}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0cm}{0.84cm}{0.42cm}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0cm}{0.84cm}{0.42cm}
% Spacing between chapter and author
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0cm}{0.84cm}{0.42cm}
%%% Chapter style
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{12pt}{\Large}

% Display chapters in the Table of Contents
\titlecontents{chapter}
  [0pt]% Left margin, optional
  {}% Code insertet above
  {\mdseries}% Numbered-entryformat
  {\mdseries}% Numberless-format
  {\contentspage} % add dotfill and pagenumber, and some vertical space between entries

% Custom command to keep the author on the same page of chaptertitle, and above it.
\newcommand{\chapterAndAuthor}[2]{%
  % #1: Author
  % #2: Chaptertitle
  \cleardoublepage
  % Keep the author and chaptertitle on same page
  \begingroup\let\cleardoublepage\relax\let\clearpage\relax
  % Set the author style
  {\fontsize{12}{14}\itshape \noindent #1}\par
  % Bring the chaptertitle closer to the authortitle
  \vspace{-3\baselineskip}
  % Add an entry to the Table of Contents, with the name of 
  % the author in emph and the chapter title
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{%
    \texorpdfstring{%
      \protect\parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-15.5pt}{
        \normalfont #1%
        \endgraf\vspace{1ex}
        \leftskip=1em #2 \dotfill
      }%
    }{#2}%
  }
  % Print the chapter
  \chapter*{#2}
  \endgroup
}


% space between table of contents
%pagestyle%
\usepackage[
  paperheight=21.0cm,
  paperwidth=13.5cm,
  twoside,
  textwidth=10.3cm,
  textheight=16.3cm,
  nohead,
  showframe, % <---- Just for the example
]{geometry}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\chapterAndAuthor{The name of the first author, The name of second author and The name of the third author}{Test Chapter One Test Chapter One Test Chapter One Test Chapter One Test Chapter One Test Chapter One Test Chapter One}
\lipsum[1-4]
\vspace{0.84cm}
\subsection*{Subheading1 without indentation}
\lipsum[1-4]
\subsection*{Subheading2 without indentation}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection*{Subheading3 without indentation}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapterAndAuthor{The name of the second author}{Test Chapter Two}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]